# Timers.timer not working after install on non dev pc

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, installshield-le

I've recently finished creating a WPF application where I used the InstallShield Limited Edition Project for the setup and deplotment, to create an exe file. 
This was done so I could install it where it was needed, however I have run into a snag shortly after installing the program on another PC.
The program is installed correct (I believe), but I've run into the problem that the timer I am using. (System.Timers.Timer) is not firing and/or working on these other PC's that are not development PC's (Ie. does not have VS15/17).
The program only works when used on a  Development PC.

I've tried to figure out why it wouldnt work and I've not been able to figure out what they are missing for them to work.
Both the PC's have the Microsoft Frameworks they should (4.5 and above), so I've run out of ideas.

This line is placed inside the constructor for the MainWindow

```
crashCheckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(_waitTime);
```

The SetTimer method

```
private void SetTimer(bool start)
    {
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        try
        {
            crashCheckTimer.Enabled = start;
            crashCheckTimer.AutoReset = true;
            crashCheckTimer.Elapsed += CrashCheckEvent;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logBuilder.ErrorLogCreation(ex, DateTime.Now, "SetTimer", NumberOfFilesToKeep);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

The CrashCheckEvent just runs some code, but is never called on the non dev pc's

**Update:**
I changes the Timers.Timer to Dispatcher.Timer on the advice of a co-worker and that have seemingly fix my issue with getting the timer to fire again.

Comment: "is never called on the non dev pc's" - how do you know that?

Comment: The try/catch in this code is entirely pointless.  It is a very evil class, it swallows any exception thrown in the Elapsed event handler.  AutoReset = true makes it extra evil.  If you don't use try/catch in *that* code then you'll never find out why "it doesn't work".  We can't see it.

Comment: Fildor- It was an assumption I made, after non of the code related to the event was ever run by the application.

Hans - When you say 'That' code? which is it exactly you are referring to?`Currently I am using the try/catch to build logs with the errors, but so far that has not happened either. But the try/catch in the SetTimer was placed there recently on the advice of another developer.

Comment: I'll make a total WAG and guess that there is something missing in the .Net Framework dependency. As an install developer that's what this seems like to me. You should always be bundling the correct .Net Fx install with your application when installing.

Comment: So far I've narrowed the error down a bit more by swapping Timers.Timer to Dispatcher.Timer and now (which it might have been before aswell I can't be certain) seem to be that a connection to an oracle database is timing out. But again, its only timing out on a non development PC. which might be due to missing something related to Oracle, however I can't currently see what it could be.